# Selected location does not represent a valid JavaFX Scene Builder installation

Tags: javafx-2, netbeans-7, java-7, scenebuilder

I have Netbeans 7.3 Beta 2 with latest Java 7 JDK on 32 bits, on Windows 8 Pro.
Problem: I removed Scene Builder 1.1 b07 and Installed the latest one b12, but now I can't set "Scene Builder Home" in Netbeans.

I get the following error:
"Selected location does not represent a valid JavaFX Scene Builder installation"
I tried pointing to all possible folders (Scene B. Folder, child folders, Oracle folder etc) (I know that it shouldn't be necessary).

The version before was OK and Netbeans detected it automatically.
I had Scene Builder 1.1 b07 before.
Now it doesn't want to be added into "Scene Builder Home" from Netbeans Options->Java->JavaFX.
That's quite annoying, because now I have to manually open each FXML from the source folder. Annoying.

I searched NetBeans bugs, but I didn't find anything. I wanted to add a new one, but I couldn't. Maybe because I already have 2 reported bugs.

Any suggestions?
I didn't remove and install NetBeans again, because I don't want to reimport the projects and configure it again just for this.

Edit:
I managed to report the bug. I had to delete the cookies from netbeans.org and log in again in order to be able to use the "report a bug" page. Let's hope for a quick fix. 
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=223994

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works flawlessly with the latest NetBeans 7.4, Java 7 JDK and SceneBuilder.

I assume it was a bug that was fixed. SceneBuilder 1.1 is a stable release now, which wasn't at that time, so this could be the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use it outside of netbeans, I faced the same Error in Ubuntu linux. [according to this bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=238520) you have to wait antil they fix it.

**right now just use it outside of netbeans**